# Why Rscript doesn't work with function as()?

Tags: r, rscript

I'm using R scripts to make some statistical calculations. When I use the interactive terminal, this code works without problems:

```r
# Load libraries to read ods tables, calcs alpha and pearson
print("Loading libraries...")
library(readODS)
# library(arules)
# library(arulesViz);
print("Done!")

# Read table ods
print("Calc results...")
table_votes = read_ods("table.ods", col_names = TRUE)

# Remove columns from dataframe where ALL values are NA
table_votes <- table_votes[,colSums(is.na(table_votes))<nrow(table_votes)]

matrix_votes <- as.matrix(table_votes)
matrix_votes[!is.finite(matrix_votes)] <- 0
transactions <- as(matrix_votes, 'transactions')
apriori(transactions)
```

But, when I'm passing   this code to the file to  run with Rscript, I have a problem with function as():

"Error: Could not find function 'as'"

I solve this using R -r my_file.R...
But, why doesn't work with Rscript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `as` function belongs to the `methods` package. Rscript doesn't load the `methods` package to save startup time (see the help of Rscript `help(Rscript)` ). You would have to tell Rscript to load the package.